# Choosing a tour of Europe

Tags: europe, tours

My brother and I are looking at touring around Europe for about 3-4 weeks. We haven't done much travelling before, so we think that it could work out much better than if we tried to organise everything ourselves. Obviously I want to look at the price, accommodation, countries visited and activities included. Is there anything else I should be asking about before deciding to take a particular tour?

Comment: Duplicate? http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5733/what-is-the-best-route-to-do-europe-in-4-weeks

Comment: Hi Casebash, welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, the question as you have left it right now is overly broad. Could you please edit it to list criteria or *what* exactly you are looking for before this question can be re-opened.

Comment: Good link: http://www.ricksteves.com/plan/tips/998tourtips.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside price + accomodation + countries + activities, you may want to know :

- Your fellow tour member. Do they allow children or grandparents to join the tour? If you are a youngster, you may want to join tour for youngster also. Travelling with children and grandparent might annoy you. ( Grandparent = slow pace , children = noisy bus )
- Do they have tour manager or tour guide? Tour guide will guide you in the city, Tour Manager does not. It means that if your tour only has tour manager, you need to plan where do you want to go.
- Does the tour provide you with breakfast, lunch and dinner? Meal in Europe is quite expensive. Some tour only provide you with breakfast.
- What is the procedure if you are missing the tour bus? Last time I have a fellow Japanese tour members that got lost twice and miss the bus.
- Does the tour have extra activities? Some of the tour give option for you to pay more for extra activities. (For example : Moulin Rouge in Paris)
- Can you extend your tour? Some of the tour able to be extended.